# Difficulty creating an XLSM file

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl, xlwings

I'm trying to **create** an `xlsm` file using `xlwings`. Or `openpyxl` if not possible with `xlwings`.

I'm on Mac so I can't use `PyWin32`.

I'm running the following python code:

```
import xlwings as xw

b = xw.Book()
b.save('test_book2.xlsm')
```

When I run that code I receive the message:
[image]

When I click 'yes' to that message I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 482, in __call__
    return self.AS_appdata.target().event(self._code, params, atts, codecs=self.AS_appdata).send(timeout, sendflags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/aem/aemsend.py", line 92, in send
    raise EventError(errornum, errormsg, eventresult)
aem.aemsend.EventError: Command failed: Parameter error. (-50)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthewbell/Desktop/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    b.save('test_book2.xlsm')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 704, in save
    return self.impl.save(path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 244, in save
    self.xl.save_workbook_as(filename=hfs_path, overwrite=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 518, in __call__
    raise CommandError(self, (args, kargs), e, self.AS_appdata) from e
appscript.reference.CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -50
        MESSAGE: Parameter error.
        COMMAND: app(pid=6198).workbooks['Book1'].save_workbook_as(filename='Macintosh HD:Users:matthewbell:Desktop:test_book2.xlsm', overwrite=True)
```

What can I do to create an xlsm file?

Comment: Use a template file that you update with the fresh data then save as...

Comment: pending issue: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/187 I'll try to get this into the next release

Comment: XLSM requires a slightly different declaration of the workbook element in the manifest. It should be possible in openpyxl to set the right can of type but Excel is still likely to complain if vbaproject.bin is missing.